# Loading wrong image into iphone

Tags: iphone, imageview

I am grabbing my image from a webservice and pasting it into my app. The webservice saves the image as img.jpg. I wanted to change the picture to a different one so I got another one and saved the picture in the same spot to img.jpg. It overwrote the file

When I look in my webservice the picture is the new one. I retrieve the image with AsyncImageView like so:

```
[AsyncImageLoader sharedLoader] cancelLoadingURL:logoView.imageURL];

logoView.imageURL=[NSURL URLWithString:logourl];
```

The logourl is filled with the proper url but it isn't grabbing the new image. It is keeping the old image there.

How can I clear that old image and use the new one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to remove the old image from the cache, because the URL is the same for both images the ImageLoader thinks they are the same.

```
[[AsyncImageCache sharedCache] removeImageForURL:logoView.imageURL];
```

EDIT:

Seems like my code was from an older version of `AsyncImageLoader`
Try this:

```
[[AsyncImageLoader defaultCache] removeObjectForKey:logoView.imageURL];
//Make sure logoView.imageURL is a NSURL
```

Comment: I get an error saying `Use of undeclared identifier "AysncImageCache" Did you mean "AsyncImageCacheKey"`

Comment: Even if I change that line to AsyncImageCacheKey it says sharedCache isn't a visible interface

Comment: @shabzco you are awesome. Thanks alot

Comment: @shabzco just to clarify, should I put that line above my cancelLoadingUrl. I am getting a leak when I set my image.